# A regex that returns a specific statement

Tags: javascript, regex

I am creating a web app that shows the authors/speakers of a video .

The problem is that the naming convention of the video is "***video topic | video author***" .

I want to get the **video author** from the video name .

I have tried using JavaScript REGEX but it seems to not work consistently .

For example : *The Good Son , The Spirit of Betrayal | Pst.Evans Kariuki*

I want to extract  ***Pst.Evans Kariuki***

Someone help me do this , thank you .

Comment: What about `title.split("|").pop()`? And what was your attempt?

Comment: You're looking for a specific statement, or the general statement after the first  pipe character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a regex for that. Just go for `split`:

```js
const video = "The Good Son , The Spirit of Betrayal | Pst.Evans Kariuki";
const author = video.split("|").pop().trim();
console.log(author);
```

Or get both elements (title and author) in one go:

```js
const video = "The Good Son , The Spirit of Betrayal | Pst.Evans Kariuki";
const [title, author] = video.split("|").map(s => s.trim());
console.log(title);
console.log(author);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\|\s*(.*)` to accomplish this. This regex will match `|` literally, eat all the whitespace and then select your text with `(.*)`

```js
const regex = /\|\s*(.*)/;
const str = `The Good Son , The Spirit of Betrayal | Pst.Evans Kariuki`;
let m = regex.exec(str);

console.log(m[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

This website is amazing :  https://regex101.com/

```js
const regex = /.*\|(.*)/;
const str = 'The Good Son , The Spirit of Betrayal | Pst.Evans Kariuki';

const ret = regex.exec(str);

console.log(ret);
console.log(ret[1].trim());
```

---

[image]